# Create frequency map from GTFS data

Tags: general-transit-feed-specification, transit

I am using QGIS to create a frequency map (how frequently does a bus/train run on a route~ every 15mins, 20, 30, 45 or 1 hr) of Greater Cleveland's RTA, from a GTFS fileset (latest version from Transitfeeds). I opened the shape, stops and routes files on QGIS, but cannot extrapolate the individual routes from either files or determine the frequency of the routes.

How can I should proceed?